# How to fix Circular dependency between resources on a logical ID

Tags: aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I trying to automate building process of my serverless application. When I set up CognitoUserPool resources I need the resources Ref CognitoUserPoolClient to create a link to redirect the client in "EmailMessage"

But the CognitoUserPoolClient need Ref CognitoUserPool

```
 CognitoUserPool:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
    Properties:
      # Generate a name based on the stage
      UserPoolName: ${self:custom.STAGE}-${self:custom.CLIENT}-user-pool
          EmailMessage: !Join
          - ''
          - - >
              You are invited to the SonderMMS platform, the world's first owned media management software. <br>
               Username: {username} <br>
               Password: {####} <br>
               Login
               <a href='
               https://${self:custom.COGNITO_DOMAIN}.auth.${self:custom.REGION}.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize?&response_type=token&redirect_uri=${self:custom.URL.${self:custom.STAGE}}&client_id=
            - !Sub '#{CognitoUserPoolClient}'

            - >
              '> here </a>.
          EmailSubject: "Email Invite"


  CognitoUserPoolClient:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolClient
    Properties:
      # Generate an app client name based on the stage
      ClientName: ${self:custom.STAGE}-${self:custom.CLIENT}-user-pool-client
      UserPoolId: !Ref CognitoUserPool
      ExplicitAuthFlows:
        - ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH
      GenerateSecret: false
```

So i get this error

> The CloudFormation template is invalid: Circular dependency between resources: [CognitoUserPoolClient, ApiGatewayAuthorizer, IdentityPool, SSMCognitoUserPoolClientId, IdentityPoolRoleMapping, SSMUserPoolId, ApiGatewayMethodTelstraPost, CognitoUserPool, SSMIdentityPoolId, ApiGatewayDeployment1559121507544, CognitoUnAuthorizedRole]

Comment: any idea on how to solve it?